# How to install many softwares in one go and replicate Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am doing a online course. Many softwares are prerequisite for the course and need to be installed on Ubuntu. I have installed all of them on my laptop at hostel. Now I have also installed Ubuntu (same version 14.04) on my lab machine on VirtualBox. There are two parts of my questions:

1. I know that, it is possible to transfer all the setting from laptop to Virtual Ubuntu, but I don't know how to do this and what would be the most effective way of doing this?
2. Is it possible to install many softwares in one shot? It takes hell lot of time to install them one-by-one.

Just for information: I have internet access on both Ubuntus.

Comment: from the terminal you can install all of them in one go with `sudo apt-get install app1 app2 ... appN`

Comment: I think he wants to install at once all the software that was installed on the other computer.

Comment: @A.B.: I have two doubts, Sylvain answered the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the program `synaptic` may help you:

`synaptic` is a graphical package manager. To use `synaptic` root privileges are required (you will be asked for a password on launch). When launched you can navigate to `File->Save Markings As...` and select a destination for the package list. (Note: since synaptic is run as root the folder "Desktop" is actually roots Desktop, not yours.)

Don't forget to check "Save full state, not only changes" in the Save As dialogue; otherwise the file will not contain all packages (or any packages at all).

You can then transfer this file to another machine and import it via synaptic using `File->Read Markings...`.

Sources: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1057608 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147845

Comment: Thanks @Kai This helped me partially, a few software got installed buy a few including chrome, anaconda... did not get installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's packages that you download [are stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178806/where-do-packages-installed-upgraded-with-apt-get-stored). A thing that might work would be to use [`scp`](https://askubuntu.com/q/58539/178596) to copy the files over the internet (via SSH) to your VM machine, and then install them using gdebi using th:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/old-ubuntu-debs    
scp -r USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS:/var/cache/apt/archives/ ~/Desktop/old-ubuntu-debs/
cd ~/Desktop/old-ubuntu-debs/
sudo dpkg -i ./*deb
```

You could alternatly copy the files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to a USB stick or another form of storage, and install from there